# Manipulate - function of a function

Tags: functions, manipulate

i'm quite new to Mathematica and I'm trying to figure out why this is not working well. Where am I wrong? I guess this is very easy for most of you.
Thanks

```
y = -3*x+2*alpha;
M[alpha_, y_] := (alpha + y);
Manipulate[Plot[M[alpha, x], {x, 0, 10}], {alpha, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Due to how you defined `M`, your `Manipulate[]` is now `Manipulate[Plot[alpha + y, {x, 0, 10}], {alpha, 0, 10}]`. Why not define `M` as `alpha - 3 x + 2 alpha`?

Comment: Because I want to recall y as a very long expression (here easy as an example).

Comment: Then define `y` as a function itself; e.g. `y[alpha_, x_] := (* stuff *)`.

Comment: I think this is the reason: 

    y[x_] := -3*x;
    M[alpha_, y_] := (alpha + y);
    Manipulate[Plot[M[alpha, y[x]], {x, 0, 10}], {alpha, 0, 10}]

I have to state y[x] inside the Manipulate rather than just y! Ps I dont know how to make the code grey as you did!

Comment: "I have to state y[x] inside the Manipulate rather than just y!" - of course; why should *Mathematica* have to guess that `y` is explicitly dependent on `x`? You have to tell the software yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Mathematica* you can work with *formulae* as well as with *functions*. It is probably best to stick to one approach and not mix.

To make sure that we do not mix up our own symbols with those that are defined in *Mathematica* already, it is good practise to:

- use `$symbolname` for a global constant (e.g. a fixed formula here)
- use `\[FormalX]`, `\[FormalY]`, ... as placeholders in formulae, since that way we can be sure, that they cannot be assigned any values by accident ([Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264))

### Working with formulae

This approach will work using formulae:

```
$y = -3 \[FormalX] + 2 \[FormalA]; (* the formula for y *)

$m = \[FormalA] + $y; (* the formula for m uses the formula for y *)

Manipulate[
    Plot[ 
         $m /. { \[FormalA] -> alpha, \[FormalX] -> x },
         {x, 0, 10}
    ], 
    {alpha, 0, 10}
]
```

### Working with functions (aka [delayed definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html#))

This will work using functions:

```
y[x_, α_] := -3 x + 2 α
m[α_, y_] := α + y

Manipulate[
    Plot[
        m[ alpha, y[x, alpha] ], 
        {x, 0, 10}
    ], 
    {alpha, 0, 10}
]
```

Comment: @Andrea In some cases it is good to remember the advice given in the *Details* section of the documentation for `Plot`: "*In some cases, it may be more efficient to use `Evaluate` to evaluate f symbolically before specific numerical values are assigned to x.*"

Comment: No need to define `y[x,alpha]` inside m[a_,y_] rather than simply y? Could you comment this ?

Comment: @AndreaG That is really what learning Mathematica's core language is all about: Patterns. In `m[ a_, y_] := ... ` the `y`refers to the locally defined symbol with regard to the definition of `m`, so it will be whatever is passed as argument to `m`. Good resource for learning, the [*Virtual Book*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html). Here `Introduction`and `Core Language` are a must.

Comment: now everything is clear. Thanks. May I ask you if you can also check my other question called "Series with Abs giving Imaginary unit as output". Is help asking allowed on this forum?

Comment: What if you are doing lots of processing, and then store the result to a variable. It's a little cumbersome to have to list every single variable to make a function definition. Any ways to make that easier?

Comment: @IonSme  I am not sure I understand your problem, as storing "lots of definitions" is exactly what Mathematica does using [DownValues](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html?q=DownValues). All you need to reference then is the symbol's name?